# Second select date not appearing in list of choices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this template :https://colorlib.com/wp/template/colorlib-wizard-15/ i need to add other div contains the date second but when i duplicate div the date days and months with yaers for second div not display so i don't know why ?
in below script :

```
<div class="form-date">
    <label for="birth_date" class="form-label">Date d'entrée</label>
    <div class="form-date-group">
        <div class="form-date-item">
            <select id="birth_month" name="birth_month"></select>
            <span class="text-input">MM</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-date-item">
            <select id="birth_date" name="birth_date"></select>
            <span class="text-input">DD</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-date-item">
            <select id="birth_year" name="birth_year"></select>
            <span class="text-input">YYYY</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I add other div the second date

```
<div class="form-date">
    <label for="birth_date" class="form-label">Date de sortie</label>
    <div class="form-date-group">
        <div class="form-date-item">
            <select id="birth_month" name="birth_month"></select>
            <span class="text-input">MM</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-date-item">
            <select id="birth_date" name="birth_date"></select>
            <span class="text-input">DD</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-date-item">
            <select id="birth_year" name="birth_year"></select>
            <span class="text-input">YYYY</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think css but i don't know what must i changer in css for this template

Thanks in advance

Comment: ID attributes **must** be unique. If you are adding the same content as shown above more than once you are violating that rule of uniqueness.

Comment: In any case, simply adding this HTML to the template you mentioned should work. If you are talking about "dates, months and years" not being displayed - it is because you haven't added any "option"s like the original template.- `<option value="01">JAN</option>`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you don't see it, the first reason I can see is @Professor Abronsius
As mentioned in the comment, it may be related to the ids, other than that, if you multiplex the form-data div, you will be able to see the output.

Comment: i add birth_date_s in the ids but not dispaly the date i think in css but i don't know which style i can changer on template https://colorlib.com/wp/template/colorlib-wizard-15/

Comment: you don't need to add extra css just need to paste same line under the exist birthday area @martine

Comment: which line i paste in style.css because i do'nt find birthday area?

Comment: you can copy the "form-date" div and paste it into "form-date", you can see inside the my answer image

Comment: css i already duplicate date form  but not displays data date....